# How to print all the key value pair in javax.naming.directory.Attributes?

Tags: java

Consider the code:

```
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = null;
SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
constraints.setTimeLimit(GloriaParams.LDAP_TIMEOUT_LIMIT);
constraints.setReturningAttributes(returningAttributes);

try {
  searchResults = HelperClass.getLdapContext().search(userId, constraints);
  Attributes attributes = ((SearchResult) searchResults.next()).getAttributes();
} catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I need to print all the key value pairs in attributes.

As of now I am using

```
LOG.info(attributes.get(searchKey).get().toString());
```

But for this one needs to know the key, but I don't know all the keys.
So how to print all the keys value pairs?

Comment: I recommend starting by looking at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/Attributes.html).

Comment: @stdunbar no, it doesn't. The question is about attributes and not NamingEnumeration.

Comment: You get a `NamingEnumeration` by calling `attributes.getAll()` or `attributes.getIDs()`. See the docs link I gave above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NamingEnumeration<String> allAttributeIDs =  attributes.getIDs();
        try {
            while(allAttributeIDs.hasMore()){
                String attributeId = allAttributeIDs.next();
                LOGGER.info(attributeId + ": " + attributes.get(attributeId).get().toString());
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            GloriaExceptionLogger.log(e, UtilServicesBean.class);
        }
```